# Hot to set termcap capability 'bw' flag?

Tags: c, shell, console, termcap

I'm studying termcap library. And I'm trying to do a line editor in the terminal. I have a cursor that can move on the line. Everything works great with one line. But if my line is bigger than terminal width, I can't return my cursor from the second line to the first using `le` command (move cursor to the left). I need to set `bw` flag to do this. function `tgetflag()` only return a value. I think that I need to set this flag using `tcsetsttr()` but can't find the right flag-macro. How can I set `bw` flag?

```
struct termios  stored_settings;
struct termios  new_settings;

tcgetattr(0, &stored_settings);
new_settings = stored_settings;
new_settings.c_lflag &= (~ICANON & ~ECHO);
new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
```

Comment: You can do this with xterm (see [*Reverse-wraparound Mode*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_)), but none of its imitators provide that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i set `bw` flag?

`auto_left_margin` (`bw`) is one of the terminal *capabilities*, i. e. it only indicates whether *`cub1` wraps from column 0 to last column*. You cannot change that behavior of the terminal, you can only query it and adapt your program appropriately, e. g. by positioning one line up and to its end with other capabilities.